# Delete not updated rows after upsert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table tha contains 3 rows like:

```
P_K, Group, Name, Age:
1,   1,     Alice, 35
2,   1,     Bob,   40
3,   2,     Eva,   19
4,   2,     Carl,  20
```

And I want (if possible) with 1 MySQL query to update Alice's age and delete Bob.

My first approach was to execute a delete query on group 1, and then insert the rows that I want. (1,  Alice, 36)

Later on I found an other approach, which was to add an extra column with a timestamp or a number, and during the upsert update this column. Then delete the rows that not mach the latest number.

Is there something else that I can do? That doesn't demand an extra column or 2 queries?

Comment: Do you have any other columns to reference ?

Comment: Don't you have a unique identifier or primary key?

Comment: sorry. I just assumed that there is a primary key

Comment: Put simply, you can't do this in a single query.

Comment: how about creating a procedure for the same? under BEGIN...UPDATE & DELETE statements will be there... @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do it by creating a procedure...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example
BEGIN

UPDATE table SET table.something=1 WHERE table.something=x;

DELETE FROM table WHERE table.something=Y;

END;

EXECUTE example;
```

I dont know if it will work or not, just trying

**Another Solution** as you don't know the value of "*Y*" (As given above in the code)

**Procedure with parameters**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example @Y <datatype> //varchar(20)
    BEGIN

    UPDATE table SET table.something=1 WHERE table.something=x;

    DELETE FROM table WHERE table.something=y;

    END;

    EXECUTE example @Y='value';
```

Comment: I have to know y parameter to run this :/ I might don't know how many rows I have to delete :/

Comment: thn only option what i can this is using procedures with parameters

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης ive updated the answer please check and let me know